# Not able to use highcharts plugins with webpack

Tags: highcharts, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to include no-data-to-display (https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-no-data-to-display) with highcharts.

I get errors like cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined. From what I can see these modules are not able to access the Highcharts object.

Here is my webpack config file

```
    var webpack = require('webpack');
    var path = require('path');
    var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV!=="production";
    var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
    var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

        module.exports = {
            entry: './main.js',
            output:{
                path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
                filename:'Build.js',
                publicPath: '/'
            },
            resolve:{
                extensions: ['', '.js'],
                root:[
                  path.resolve(__dirname)
                ],
                moduleDirectories:[path.resolve(__dirname,'node_modules')],
                alias:{
                    'highcharts':               'lib/vendor/highcharts.src',
                    'highcharts_more':          'lib/vendor/highchartmore.src',
                    'highcharts_gauge':         'lib/vendor/solid-gauge.src', 
                    'highcharts_no_data':    'lib/vendor/modules/highcharts/no-data-to-display',
                },
               }
               module:{
                   loaders:[
                      {   test: __dirname+'/lib/vendor/highcharts.src' ,
                        loader: 'exports?Highcharts!imports?jquery,proj4'
                    },
                    {   test: 'highcharts_more' ,
                        loader: 'imports?highcharts'
                    },
                     {   test: __dirname+'/lib/vendor/modules/highcharts/no-data-to-display',
                        loader: 'imports?highcharts,highcharts_more'
                    },
                   ] 
               },
               plugins:[
                new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                    $: "jquery",
                    jQuery: "jquery",
                    "window.jQuery":"jquery",
                   _:"underscore",
                  Highcharts:"highcharts"
               })
             ]
        ]}
```

Comment: When loading a Highcharts module or plugin you should initialize it before using like with the funnel module [here](http://www.highcharts.com/blog/192-use-highcharts-to-create-charts-in-react). So your code could look like: `var Highcharts = require('highcharts'), myHCmodule = require('my/HC/module'); [...] myHCmodule(Highcharts);` Or you could do it like it's done with the exporting module in [Docs\(http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/install-from-npm) - see first code block on that site.